# Overlay images in Gallery View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

I would like to add ImageButton to Gallery items in an overlay type functionality. Specifically I would like to have 4 buttons to be placed at the top of every image in the gallery and trigger actions when they get pressed.

Thank you very much for any help or hint in this matter. Below is my XML file.

```
    <include layout="@layout/topnav_bar"/>

            <!-- These are my buttons -->
    <include layout="@layout/topbuttons"/>


    <Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/runway"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:spacing="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <include layout="@layout/bottomnav_bar"/>
```

This is my TOPBUTTONS XML

```
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibuy" 
    android:src="@drawable/ishop"
    android:onClick="@string/ibuy"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_height="50dp" 
    android:layout_width="20dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageButton 
    android:src="@drawable/izoom"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_height="50dp" 
    android:layout_width="20dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/fblike"
    android:src="@drawable/ishare"
    android:onClick="@string/postToFaceBook"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_height="50dp" 
    android:layout_width="20dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/ilove"
    android:src="@drawable/ilove"
    android:onClick="@string/rateIt"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_height="50dp" 
    android:layout_width="20dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RelativeLayout, something on the lines

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation= "vertical"
    >
    <include layout="@layout/topnav_bar"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <!-- These are my buttons -->
        <include 
            layout="@layout/topbuttons"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />
        <Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/runway"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>        
    <include layout="@layout/bottomnav_bar"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the buttons dont get applied to each image.  Only one set of buttons get created.  Let's say I have 12 images in my gallery, I want each of the individual images to have their own set of buttons.  Maybe I need to manipulate the image its self and OVERLAY the image?  I'm not sure what the correct approach is.

Comment: OK I though you have one image per screen. If you did not find a solution yet, try creating a new adapter like you do for ListView and set it for your Gallery.